# Bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found. - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am developing a spring application with spring-security and login with google but I get this error when executing the application:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Method springSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'clientRegistrationRepository' in 'OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration' not loaded because OAuth2 Clients Configured Condition registered clients is not available


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' in your configuration.
```

My application.yml:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/manager
        username: application_spring
        password: application_spring

    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
security:
      oauth2:
        client:
          registration:
            google:
              client-id: {client id}
              client-secret: {client-secret}
              redirectUri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
              scope:
                - email
                - profile
app:
  auth:
    tokenSecret: 926D96C90030DD58429D2751AC1BDBBC
    tokenExpirationMsec: 864000000
  oauth2:
    # After successfully authenticating with the OAuth2 Provider,
    # we'll be generating an auth token for the user and sending the token to the
    # redirectUri mentioned by the frontend client in the /oauth2/authorize request.
    # We're not using cookies because they won't work well in mobile clients.
    authorizedRedirectUris:
      - http://localhost:3000/oauth2/redirect
      - myandroidapp://oauth2/redirect
      - myiosapp://oauth2/redirect
```

And my SecurityConfig class:

```
package com.manager.manager.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.AuthorizationRequestRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.manager.manager.security.oatuh2.CustomOAuth2UserService;
import com.manager.manager.security.oatuh2.HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
import com.manager.manager.security.oatuh2.OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.manager.manager.security.oatuh2.OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import com.manager.manager.security.utils.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.manager.manager.security.utils.TokenAuthenticationFilter;
import com.manager.manager.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    /*
      By default, Spring OAuth2 uses HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository to save
      the authorization request. But, since our service is stateless, we can't save it in
      the session. We'll save the request in a Base64 encoded cookie instead.
    */
    @Bean
    public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/error",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                        .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                        .and()
                    .redirectionEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                        .and()
                    .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                        .and()
                    .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

        // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }



}
```

To do this app I was following this tutorial : 
https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-2/

Anybody knows what could be the problem? 
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like and indentation issue, security property must be beneath the spring property like so

```
spring:
   security:
```

Comment: There is also a chance the configuration is mistyped, in my case I was missing the `oauth2` option in `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration...`

Answer (score 3):

I found this also happens if:

- Your active spring profile isn't defined correctly
- The default profile is missing the OAuth2 information (e.g. client ID and secret).

You can read a bit about it in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73656510/8641842); it's sufficient to triage this by looking for this error message in the logs:

```
No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
```

Comment: I get this problem running with Eclipse 2022-12. It was resolved in Eclipse 2023-03.

Answer (score -2):

The author has given the complete source code in the following github link. Download the code and build it and try to run it. In this project there are two types of project, one is java type which you have to build using maven and another is react project which you have to build using yarn just like npm package manager.

To run the project "react-social", you have to build using the command `yarn install && yarn build && yarn start`. To build other spring based project "spring-social", you have to use the command `mvn clean install`. You can also run the command directly `mvn spring-boot:run`.

The author has given instruction about to run the project in ReadMe.md file in github. I would suggest first build and run the spring based project and then react-social project.

https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo