# ClientRegistrationRepository Bean is not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to configure an OAuth2 client using Spring Boot. I have the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And I have added these properties to my application.yaml:

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          azure:
            client-id: ****
            client-secret: ****
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
        provider:
          azure:
            authorization-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/2fdb7e27-9b62-44f7-a0fe-9836eaa1f161/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
            token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/2fdb7e27-9b62-44f7-a0fe-9836eaa1f161/oauth2/v2.0/token
            jwk-set-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/2fdb7e27-9b62-44f7-a0fe-9836eaa1f161/discovery/v2.0/keys
```

As I understand it from the Spring documentation, this should be enough to auto-configure a ClientRegistrationRepository ("Spring Boot 2.x auto-configuration binds each of the properties under spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.[registrationId] to an instance of ClientRegistration and then composes each of the ClientRegistration instance(s) within a ClientRegistrationRepository. The auto-configuration also registers the ClientRegistrationRepository as a @Bean in the ApplicationContext so that it is available for dependency-injection, if needed by the application.".

I have the following code:

```
package com.sky.bnc.azurespring

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient

@Configuration
class WebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun authorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository: ClientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository: OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository): OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager {
        val authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder
                .builder()
                .authorizationCode()
                .refreshToken()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build()

        val authorizedClientManager = DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository)
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider)

        return authorizedClientManager
    }

    @Bean
    fun webClient(authorizedClientManager: OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager): WebClient {
        val oauth2Client = ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager)
        oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("azure")

        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
                .build()
    }
}
```

But when I try and run the application I get this error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method authorizedClientManager in com.sky.bnc.azurespring.WebConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't understand what the problem is, I have followed many examples and it seems like it should just be working.

Answer (score 4):

The `ClientRegistrationRepository` refers to the configuration of the OAuth client in a blocking environment, not reactive. In case you build your application to be fully reactive, consider using the `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` implementation. Spring security project has an [example project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/reactive/webflux/java/oauth2/webclient/src/main/java/example/WebClientConfiguration.java) of how to use that one.

However, you could still mix the reactive and blocking approaches in the same application, although not terribly recommended, there is still a use case for that. For this, you only need to add the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency, so that the blocking servlet implementation is added to the classpath. You could watch [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6a1F4PWOYiM) where this approach is used.

Comment: official docs here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/client/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Define the following properties:

1. azure.activedirectory.client-id=
2. azure.activedirectory.client-secret=
3. azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=
4. azure.activedirectory.authorization-clients.graph.scopes=https://graph.microsoft.com/Analytics.Read,
   email

Answer (score 1):

Indentation issue,

```
spring:
 security:
```

ref : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61128936/bean-of-type-org-springframework-security-oauth2-client-registration-clientregi)

Comment: This wasn't the answer to my issue, but as it turns out, I was missing this section. Adding it and providing the correct parameters fixed it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are  facing is due to the configuration in **application.yaml** file. Please check everything is correct.

Since you are implementing oauth for Azure AD the configuration must look like below,

```
# Specifies your Active Directory ID:
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222

# Specifies your App Registration's Application ID:
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id=11111111-1111-1111-1111-1111111111111111

# Specifies your App Registration's secret key:
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret=AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz==

# Specifies the list of Active Directory groups to use for authorization:
azure.activedirectory.user-group.allowed-groups=Users
```

For complete step-by-step guide please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory).